# Inserción en 2 tablas dependientes mysql-java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda sobre cuál es la forma correcta de hacer la siguiente operación:

Tengo que hacer un `insert` en una tabla y una vez hecho eso debo obtener el `id` de dicho registro para insertar inmediatamente en otra tabla que tiene un *foreign key* de dicho `id` de forma automática.

- Base de datos: **mysql**
- Lenguaje: **java**

Ejemplo:

```
tabla1 (id, sNombre, sApellido)
tabla2 (id, evento, idTabla1)
```

Insertar `tabla1`, obtener `id` de registro e inmediatamente poder realizar registro en la `tabla2`.

---

```
public DriverManagerDataSource Conectar(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    return dataSource;
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "encu/agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Agregar(encu e,HttpServletRequest request){
        String sql = "insert into encuesta (STATUS,CONTRATANTE,ENCUESTA,CONFIG) values (?,?,?,?)";
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,e.getIdStatus(),e.getEncCon(),e.getNoEnc(),e.getEncCon());
        String sqlLast = "select last_insert_id()";
        int result = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sqlLast);
        System.out.println(result);  //siempre retorna 0
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:index.htm");
}
```

@OscarGarcia

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código java que has usado o probado para adaptarlo a tus necesidades?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar en ella el código? Cómo comentario puede cortarse y no se lee bien. Recuerda que lo más importante no es el establecimiento de la conexión, si no el código con el que ejecutas la consulta SQL. Gracias.

Comment: hola una disculpa soy nuevo en stackoverflow lo coloque como comentario saludos @OscarGarcia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edición tras conocer el código Java usado:**

En vez de hacer uso de [`JdbcTemplate.update( String )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-) que solicita una cadena de caracteres que corresponde con una consulta SQL, haremos uso de la [`JdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-).

En la documentación de Spring aparece [`GeneratedKeyHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html):

> The standard implementation of the `KeyHolder` interface, to be used for holding auto-generated keys (as potentially returned by JDBC `insert` statements).
>
> Create an instance of this class for each `insert` operation, and pass it to the corresponding `JdbcTemplate` or `SqlUpdate` methods.

En castellano:

> La implementación estándar de la interfaz `KeyHolder`, para ser usada para almacenar las claves auto-generadas (como pueden ser devueltas por las consultas JDBC `insert`).
>
> Crea una instancia de esta clase por cada operación `insert`, y pásala al método `JdbcTemplate` o `SqlUpdate` correspondiente.

Así que podemos hacer uso de una consulta preparada normal con soporte para obtener la clave generada automáticamente ([`prepareStatement(prepareStatement(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int))) a través de la clase de Spring [`PreparedStatementCreator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementCreator.html):

```
GeneratedKeyHolder clave = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
/* Hacemos otro uso diferente de this.jdbcTemplate.update */
this.jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        /* Creamos la consulta preparada como hacemos habitualmente */
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO encuesta (STATUS, CONTRATANTE, ENCUESTA, CONFIG) values (?,?,?,?)",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
        );
        /* Asignamos los valores como una consulta preparada normal */
        statement.setString(1, e.getIdStatus());
        statement.setString(2, e.getEncCon());
        statement.setString(3, e.getNoEnc());
        statement.setString(4, e.getEncCon());
        return statement;
    }
}, clave);
/* Ahora sí que tenemos la clave generada automáticamente */
System.out.println(clave.getKey().longValue());
```

---

**Respuesta original:**

Puedes hacer uso de [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO tabla1 (sNombre, sApellido) VALUES
  ('Nuevo', 'Usuario');

INSERT INTO tabla2 (evento, idTabla1) VALUES
  ('Nuevo evento del nuevo usuario', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vZhwn1gFkWz5GWRc4h8JBB/0).

La función `LAST_INSERT_ID()` te devolverá el valor usado en el campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` durante la última consulta `INSERT`. Si tienes que insertar varios campos deberías almacenar dicho valor en una variable de sesión.

Comment: Un apunte, esto hay que hacerlo en una transacción, si no el resultado puede no ser el esperado.

Comment: Hola @JDev. No es necesario que sea en una transacción porque el resultado de la función no se va a alterar aunque otra persona agregue un nuevo registro a la tabla. Siempre devuelve el valor autonumérico creado en el último `INSERT` de la conexión actual. Sólo si se cierra y abre la conexión o se hace un nuevo `INSERT` entonces el valor se pierde.

Comment: En el enlace de la documentación que facilité se puede leer: *The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a **per-connection** basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by that client.*

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda el método funciona pero solo si estoy en mysql estoy usando spring mvc y JdbcTemplate el problema es que al ejecutar el codigo en java siempre retorna 0 ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu código? Si quieres obtener el `id` en el lado de java necesitas unos cambios.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "insert into persona (nombre,apellido) values (?,?)";
        //this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,e.getIdStatusEncu(),e.getEncContratante(),e.getNoEncuestas(),e.getEncConfig());
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps
                        = connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id_persona"}); //id de nuestra tabla
                ps.setInt(1, p.getNombre());
                ps.setInt(2, p.getApe());
                return ps;
            }
        },
                keyHolder);
System.out.println(keyHolder.getKey()); //acceder al id generado
```

gracias por la ayuda